# error record and play audio in android

Tags: android, audio

i've been trying to record and play recorded audio in android . I've used MediaRecorder and MediaPlayer class for the same.

My code contain 3 segments:
startrecording()
stoprecording()
playaudio

But there's an error in my code fragement and whenever i execute it ,the startrecording() function implements catch block.

```
 package hare.krishna;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;


public class Recordplay2Activity extends Activity 
{    
    Button play1,record1,stop1;
    TextView status1;
    MediaRecorder m1=null;
    MediaPlayer m2=null;
    String path;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        play1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        record1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.record);
        stop1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
        status1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);

        OnClickListener recordListener = new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                startrecording();
            }
        };

        OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                stoprecording();
            }
        };

        OnClickListener playListener = new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                playaudio();
            }
        };

        record1.setOnClickListener(recordListener);
        stop1.setOnClickListener(stopListener); 
        play1.setOnClickListener(playListener);    

    }


    public void startrecording() 
    {       
        status1.setText("GET READY FOR RECORDING");
        try
        {       
        m1=new MediaRecorder();
        m1.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        m1.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        m1.setOutputFile(path);
        m1.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        m1.prepare();
        m1.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            status1.setText("ERROR IN startrecording FUNCTION ");
        }
    }

    public void stoprecording()
    {
        try
        {
        status1.setText("TIME TO STOP MEDIA");
        m1.stop();
        m1.reset();
        m1.release();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            status1.setText("ERROR IN stoprecording FUNCTION");
        }
    }

    public void playaudio()
    {
        status1.setText("PLAYING RECORDER AUDIO");
        try
        {
            m2=new MediaPlayer();
            m2.setDataSource("/sdcard/output.3gp");
            m2.prepare();
            m2.start();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR in playaudio FUNCTION");

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Comment: What error are you getting? What does the logcat say? Please post the full stacktrace in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I changed `AudioEncoder` from:

```
m1.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
```

to:

```
m1.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT)
```